# Добавление элемента в массив, который определяется классом Swift

Tags: xcode, swift

Есть определенный класс

```
class Weapon {
var name: String
var atack: Int
var def: Int
var image: UIImage

init(name:String, atack:Int, def:Int, image:UIImage) {
    self.name = name
    self.atack = atack
    self.def = def
    self.image = image
} }
```

Так же есть массив, который определяется классом выше

```
var weapon: [Weapon] = []
```

Изначально пустой. Вопрос такой, как добавить новый элемент в массив, при этом иметь возможность сохранить его через userDefaults. С помощью append добавить можно, но тогда не сохраняются данные

добавляю так в массив, но тогда при сохранении выдает ошибку

```
let we = (Weapon(name: "ddadadadaad", atack: 24, def: 34))
    weapon.append(we)
```

Comment: Непонятно что Вы хотите. Здесь ошибка не при сохранении сразу должна быть, а при инициализации.

Comment: а в чем проблема? с инициализацией все хорошо. 
кроме того, реализовал сохранения с помощью присваивания классу NSCoding и NSObject
Попозже код выложу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем нижнем куске кода в инициализаторе отсутствует UIImage... может проблема в этом? 
При добавлении переменной класса Weapon в массив через append - все ее содержимое должно сохранятся... иначе какой во всем этом добавлении смысл?

Comment: это я не доглядел при добавлении коммента, а так все там есть, проблема не в этом. Просто UserDefaults в простом своем виде, не умеет сохранять такие сложные массивы

Comment: Тогда попробуйте использовать **NSArray** вместо обычного... вот что написано в мануалах от func set(_ value: Any?, forKey defaultName: String):
`parameter can be only property list objects: NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. For NSArray and NSDictionary objects, their contents must be property list objects. `